# GET Request in For Loop only returning response from the final loop index. Preceding ones return empty

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests, get

I'm running get requests to a URL, using lines in a text file as arguments in said get requests. The issue I'm finding is that the responseind.json() is only returning the get request related to the LAST line of the txt file. All preceding lines return []. Code below, any ideas?

```
with open('industries.txt') as industry_file:
       for line in industry_file:
        start = time.time()
        responseind = requests.get("https:URL" + "".join(line) + "?token=My key")
        print(responseind.json())
```

Comment: is it possible that you are sending too many requests to the server?

Comment: could you show what response get for last line of text file also print `responseid.text`. my guess is perhaps the json happens to be an empty list for those

Comment: Please check that response status is also 200 or 201 so that the request was succesful. Are you sure that endpoint encoding is json ?

Comment: @AndrewRyan: i tried adding a wait between the consecutive calls to slow it down (went up to 15 seconds of wait), didn't help.

Comment: @MichałDarowny: i checked the response status within the for loop to confirm success, 200 every time.

Comment: Then go with Debugger over this loop and check the whole response object, you could print it out too. Seems like response is not really a json object. Try printing a value of `.text`

Comment: @MichałDarowny but i am getting a response in json, just not for all the values on the test file; only the last index

Comment: @Amostafa if you put one of the earlier urls into the browser do you see a json response?

Comment: @AndrewRyan hey Andrew, yeah I do. even tried doing this without the text file, and manually putting in the variables - works fine. super frustrating! been stuck on this issue all day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your requests are not working properly is that you are just using the entire line in the text file (which ends in a new line character '\n'). The reason why your last request may be getting a response is that there is no new line after that id (the file ends) therefore not having that character which gives a valid id to look for.

```
with open('industries.txt') as industry_file:
    for line in industry_file:
        start = time.time()
        responseind = requests.get("https:URL" + "".join(line).replace('\n', '') + "?token=My key")
        print(responseind.json())
```